# awk in python: How to use awk scripts in a python class?

Tags: python, awk

I am trying to run an awk script using python, so I can process some data.

Is there any way to get an awk script to run in a python class without using the system class to invoke it as shell process? The framework where I run these python scripts does not allow the use of a subprocess call, so I am stuck either figuring out a way to convert my awk script in python, or if is possible, running the awk script in python.

Any suggestions? My awk script basically read a text file and isolate blocks of proteins that contains a specific chemical compound (the output is generated by our framework; I've add an example of how does it looks like below) and isolate them printing them out on a different file.

```
    buildProtein compoundA compoundB
    begin fusion
    Calculate : (lots of text here on multiple lines)
    (more lines)
    Final result - H20: value CO2: value Compound: value 
    Other Compounds X: Value Y: value Z:value

    [...another similar block]
```

So for example if I build a protein and I need to see if in the compounds I have CH3COOH in the final result line, if it does I have to take the whole block, starting from the command "buildProtein", until the beginning of the next block; and save it on a file; and then move to the next and see if it has again the compound that I am looking for...if it does not have it I skip to the next, until the end of the file (the file has multiple occurrence of the compound that I search for, sometimes they are contiguous while other times they are alternate with blocks that has not the compound.

Any help is more than welcome; banging my head for weeks now and after finding out this site I decided to ask for some help.

Thanks in advance for your kindness!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't use the *subprocess* module, the best bet is to recode your AWK script in Python.  To that end, the *fileinput* module is a great transition tool with and AWK-like feel.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond.

Should i then load the whole file, process it with file input and then  save the output on an external file? I Imagine that finding a fitting example for my pretty unique case is hard :)

Comment: @user1006198: Your case isn't unique.  It's just that your design is poor because AWK is so bad.  Load the whole file.  Process the whole file.  Save the whole output.  Discard AWK entirely.  Begin with just the relevant "calculations" and ignore the artifacts of AWK's limitations.  Python is (in many ways) going to be simpler.  Since it's new, of course, you have to learn it first, making it seem complex.

Comment: :-) Fileinput will let you process the input line-by-line just like AWK does.  You can emit output to another file with "print >> somefile, some_line_of_text".

Comment: I see; I was not aware of this module, and now reading how it works it seems to be very similar; thanks for pointing that out Raymond!

Comment: @S.Lott: Indeed I understand that the design is poor, but I cannot just go to my team and say "we gotta do everything from scratch"; so I am trying to transition without throwing everything done before away...if possible I would like to have an ordered list instead of a txt input, or even better, an object that i can parse in a class; but I am not that good to write a port from Assembly (that is what our equipment use for the exporter) to python or C++, so gotta rely on the equipment team to write it, and it takes time as you can imagine :)

Comment: @user1006198: "I cannot just go to my team and say "we gotta do everything from scratch"?  Why not?  You do actually have to rewrite everything from scratch.  Why lie about it?

Comment: is a matter of logistics and time; one thing is me writing a simple parser for the logs; another is to change their side to make a different output :)

Answer (score 1):

[Python's re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) can help, or, if you can't be bothered with regular expressions and just need to do some quick field seperation, you can use [the built in str `.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and  [`.find()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) functions.

Comment: Thanks Aphex; tried to write an RE but failed miserably; since I do not know too much about pure RE; with AWK is easy to find and isolate blocks since you can work with the print statement on and off, but with a pure RE I am not really sure how to deal with it.
The main objective is to find an occurrence of a compound in a block, and save the whole block if the compound is in it, so this require not only to find something in a block (that would be easy enough for me), but once you find the occurrence, get everything from the first line until the first line of the next block, and so on

Comment: @user1006198: Comments are a terrible place to explain your **real** problem.  Consider updating your question to explain your problem.  Examples help.  Awk's `/pattern/ code` construct uses RE's.  It translates to `if re.match(r'pattern',line): code` in Python.  Slightly more punctuation than AWK.  Same regular expression language in the pattern.

Comment: Plus, during my brief stint as a UNIX admin, the thing I used awk the most for is field seperation - such as in `awk -F ','` to seperate comma delimited fields, and so on. This too can be easily done in python by just reading a file with `readlines()` and iterating through each line and using `.split()`.

Comment: Indeed is hard to add info in comments; that's why I did all that i can to state my problem in the main post; if it is not clear please let me know and i will be more than happy to make it more readable (english is not my first language, doing my best)

Answer (score 1):

I have barely started learning AWK, so I can't offer any advice on that front.  However, for some python code that does what you need:

```
class ProteinIterator():
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = open(file, 'r')
        self.first_line = self.file.readline()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        "returns the next protein build"
        if not self.first_line:     # reached end of file
            raise StopIteration
        file = self.file
        protein_data = [self.first_line]
        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            if line.startswith('buildProtein ') or not line:
                self.first_line = line
                break
            protein_data.append(line)
        return Protein(protein_data)

class Protein():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
        for line in data:
            if line.startswith('buildProtein '):
                self.initial_compounds = tuple(line[13:].split())
            elif line.startswith('Final result - '):
                pieces = line[15:].split()[::2]   # every other piece is a name
                self.final_compounds = tuple([p[:-1] for p in pieces])
            elif line.startswith('Other Compounds '):
                pieces = line[16:].split()[::2]   # every other piece is a name
                self.other_compounds = tuple([p[:-1] for p in pieces])
    def __repr__(self):
        return ("Protein(%s)"% self._data[0])
    @property
    def data(self):
        return ''.join(self._data)
```

What we have here is an iterator for the buildprotein text file which returns one protein at a time as a `Protein` object.  This `Protein` object is smart enough to know it's inputs, final results, and other results.  You may have to modify some of the code if the actual text in the file is not exactly as represented in the question.  Following is a short test of the code with example usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_data = """\
buildProtein compoundA compoundB
begin fusion
Calculate : (lots of text here on multiple lines)
(more lines)
Final result - H20: value CO2: value Compound: value 
Other Compounds X: Value Y: value Z: value"""

    open('testPI.txt', 'w').write(test_data)
    for protein in ProteinIterator('testPI.txt'):
        print(protein.initial_compounds)
        print(protein.final_compounds)
        print(protein.other_compounds)
        print()
        if 'CO2' in protein.final_compounds:
            print(protein.data)
```

I didn't bother saving values, but you can add that in if you like.  Hopefully this will get you going.